# Android images and buttons

Tags: android, image, button

What should I use if I want to have buttons on an image? I mean, being able to click on certain points of an image and see some info.

---

What if I want to display text on that points? Imagine I am having a map of my neighbor for example, and I want some info to be displayed (for example my home). And if someone press on my home he could see further details, like my name, my phone and so on. The image(aka the map) will be stable, it wont change, like a background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement the method `onTouch` from the interface `OnTouchListener`. For example:

```
OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public false onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(!event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return false; //If the touch event was not putting the finger down on the screen, return false(Actions may be move, up, and so on)
        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();
        if(x and y are in some range)
            doFirstThing();
        else if(x and y are in another range..)
            doSecondThing();
        //... and so on...
        //In the end, you must return a boolean saying whether you "consumed" the event - if you handled the event or not.
    }
}
```

And don't forget to set the listener as the `OnTouchListener` for your `ImageView`!

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks! As I understand, the x,y will be the co-ordinates of the point, right? They will be expressed in what form? Pixels or in something else?

Comment: Pixels indeed. `getX` and `getY` return pixels in local coordinates (Current view). If you want the on-screen coordinates, use `getRawX` and `getRawY`.

Comment: Ok and something else. How do I know the coordinates for my point? I mean in order to set the range I have to know it, right? The question is how is it measured?

Comment: It is measured in pixels. And you decide the ranges on your own.. You have a picture with given dimensions in pixels, so find the ranges you need.

Comment: Ok thanks! So when you say local coordinates, you refer to the pixels of the image, not the pixels on each screen? I mean, those dimensions returned by the getX and getY will be the same, regardless of the screen they are displayed. Am I right?

Comment: Yes (Unless the image/view is scaled. If it is, I'm not sure whether the return pixels are scaled too, or they will remain what they should be). If you want the screen pixels, use `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe for what you are trying to achieve you don't need to use buttons. Instead, create a custom view, in your onDraw method draw the images and handle the onTouch events as Jong suggested. Once you detected a click on your home for example, you could create another view with info about it and display it to user.

For info on how to create custom view you may refer to [this queestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568519/android-custom-view-based-on-layout-how) for example. Google around for it