# Best way to extract a series of repeated View components into its own View?

Tags: refactoring, android-view, android

In a basic game app I want to create, I have a menu screen with a listing of boxes, each representing a level the user can select.

The boxes are `RelativeLayout`s with other elements packaged inside them, like some `TextView`s, a `ProgressBar` and a `Button`.

Since I have many of these boxes in my layout, I was wondering, is there any way I can extract each box into its own `View`? I feel this would make my app more clean and organized and is good for practice.

I looked into "Creating Custom Views", but it seems to include a lot of complicated measuring and I haven't been able to find anything about including existing Views into my Views (for example, including a `ProgressBar` in my custom View).

Here's a screenshot to give you an idea what I'm doing

[image: Android Repeating View]

Comment: tried extracting this View Hierarchy to a Fragment and reused?

Answer (score 3):

A custom view sounds like the solution. I assume that beside the common xml you have a common functionality (when "go" is pressed etc).

The way I'd go about it is extracting the common layout and extending a relative layout which will inflate that layout.

It's actually been answered before here : [Android: Custom view based on layout: how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568519/android-custom-view-based-on-layout-how)

And you can use the android notes : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

**Edit 2** (alternative, include tag):

This way also starts with extracting the common layout to another xml. Using the tag include (or merge tag) you can inject the xml to wherever you want in your layouts. The UI 'component' will look the same and for most cases that might provide an answer for your needs.

more on that at : 
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

**Edit 1** (extending view, with sample code):

Step 1 - defining the layout of the view - this is the common UI part, just a bunch of views.

Note that the use of the merge tag can save a level in the layout hierarchy

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Level"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtLevel"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
    android:text="Go"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step 2 - creating a class to extend View (in this case RelativeLayout) :
inflating the xml and setting some onClick event handler.

```
public class SampleCustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    public SampleCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        // Adding the layout defined in the xml to my view
        this.addView(((LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_view_layout, null));

        // Some sample event handling to the view
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGo)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                ((Button)v).setText("Went");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Step 3 - using the view in some other layout in the app

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <com.example.drorfichman.stuff.SampleCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.drorfichman.stuff.SampleCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Step 4 - getting a reference to the view from activity/fragment

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // This is one of the views
        SampleCustomView v = (SampleCustomView)findViewById(R.id.myView);
    }
}
```

And the result (oh the horror)!

[image: emulator]

Comment: I actually didn't find an example in google. hoped to save both of us some time, I guess it's hiding.. Tried to keep it simple and relevant to your question. There's really nothing surprising here.